# Checked checkboxes vs. unchecked checkboxes

Tags: usability, checkboxes, default

I'm improving the usability of an insurance premium calculator. There are a number of major options which will be toggled on/off using checkboxes.

Should I check them all on by default and display all the features or let the users check as they progress and build their own product?

Comment: It's a business question, not an UX question (answers are, I guess, pretty different)

Comment: You should ask your users whether you should do this!

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here for this to be answerable; you're basically asking "should my product's features be default or optional?"  Depends on what the features are, what percentage of users are likely to use each of them, whether they are standalone or have interdependencies, what user expectations might be based on similar products, what you mean by "build their own product"...

Comment: Why not ask the users simple questions like "Are you a hown owner?", "Should the insurance cover your familiy too?" and then give them a correctly configured calculator to use The user should be able to use the Calculator without needing too much specialized knowledge about the topic.

Answer (score 3):

**From a users perspective**; you should ask your users whether or not they want them checked or not. You can do either A/B testing or prototype testing.

**From a business perspective**; you should pre-check the ones that your company wants users to check so they have to uncheck them if they don't want them checked, I know this sounds silly but it's how the marketing/sales world works.

**Conclusion**: There isn't a definitive answer we can give you on this forum. It depends on the perspective and what type of users are in your audience.

Answer (score 1):

- If these options are in a settings page where **the user, after using the product, can configure them then preselect** the ones that are needed for the product to work correctly in the first place.
- If these options are in a step by step process where **the user has to configure things before using the product then don't preselect** them. The user needs to select what he wants and leave unselected what he doesn't.

(As an example I always have to be sure I read all these check boxes when I sign up for something as some websites preselect some options, or some even make me select a checkbox to deny an action, to receive publicity emails).

Answer (score 0):

I will put them unchecked, and add a link or a extra box for "check all"..
Pre-checked boxes is ok when you are conditioned for next step or some procedure..
Like terms and condition,etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you to do some ground research on your users and find out what are the features they generally opt while using the premium calculator. Based on that result you can easily figure out which of them should be kept “On”/ “Checked” by-default and which should not.

As you must be working for B2C, the remaining features could be suggested to users next to user’s final calculations, as projected comparative score along with proper justifications with using all the features (options) checked.

Answer (score 0):

This UI should be designed based on the product strategy and business goals. Nothing to do with the UX here.

Comment: Product strategy and business goals have a lot to do with UX.